# Display final results on the same page from a dynamic drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a multiple drop down that goes from Country/State/city/destination.

What I want this plugin to do next, is once the destination menu is selected, the page will automatically display some general information about that destination on the same page without reloading.

The general info is in the same table as my destination drop down menu is, but under different columns.

So how can I get this information to display its self possibly in a text box or something similar only when the final distention menu is selected.

Here are some parts of my code thus far, I don't believe posting everything is necessary and might be a little confusing. PS-I am a beginner.

This is an example of my javascript which calls from my ajax.php file for the array to populate the drop down menu...

```
jQuery(".wrap").on('change', '#city', function() {
            var querystr2 = 'cityid=' +jQuery('#city :selected').val();
            jQuery.post("<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/Destination_Drop_Down_Menu/ajax.php", querystr2, function(data) {
                if(data.errorcode ==0){
                    jQuery('#descbo').html(data.chtml)
                }else{
                    jQuery('#descbo').html(data.chtml)
                }
            }, "json");
        });
```

This is part of my ajax.php file that previous example of jQuery is pulling information from.

```
$city_id = isset($_POST['cityid']) ? $_POST['cityid'] : 0;
if ($city_id <> 0) {
$errorcodeD = 0;
$strmsg = "";
$sqlD="SELECT * from destination WHERE IDCity = ". $city_id . " ORDER BY name;";
$resultD=mysql_query($sqlD);
$contD=mysql_num_rows($resultD);
if(mysql_num_rows($resultD)){
    $chtmlD = '<select name="destination" id="destination"><option value="0">--Select   Destination--</option>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultD)){
        $chtmlD .= '<option   value="'.$row['IDDestination'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    $chtmlD .= '</select>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcodeD,"chtml"=>$chtmlD));
}else{
    $errorcodeD = 1;
    $strmsg = '<font style="color:#F00;">No Destination available</font>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcodeD,"chtml"=>$strmsg));
}
```

And MY html section that would display everything.

```
<h2>Destination</h2>
        <div class="wrap" id="descbo">
        </div>
```

So basically what ever destination the user chooses, the specific information for that destination will render its self on the screen in separate boxes or text areas.

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be posting "raw" php in your AJAX, Line 3 of the jQuery.  This can't be executed.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Everything is functioning properly. Just trying to figure out the next step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you want your php script to return data from your `destination` table when a particular destination is selected. You said you don't want the page to reload, but I'll assume you're OK with issuing another AJAX request to the server. If that's the case, you can simply create another delegated jQuery handler for the `destination` `<select>`:

```
jQuery(".wrap").on('change', '#destination', function() {
    var data = {destinationid: this.value};
    jQuery.post("url/to/script.php", data)
        .done(function(response) {
            jQuery('#descbo').html(response.html);
        });
```

Then, in your PHP, you could have something like this:

```
$destination_id = isset($_POST['destinationid']) ? $_POST['destinationid'] : 0;
...
$sqlD="SELECT * from destination WHERE ID = ". $destination_id . " ORDER BY name;";
$resultD=mysql_query($sqlD);
if(mysql_num_rows($resultD)){
    $chtmlD = '<div class="destination">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultD)){
        $chtmlD .= '<p>' . $row['whatever'] . '</p>';
    }
    $chtmlD .= '</div>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcodeD,"chtml"=>$chtmlD));
} else {
...
}
```

That will replace your original destination `<select>` with a div containing the destination description (or whatever the content is). If you don't want to replace the select, you could simply have the JS update a different element on the page, e.g.

```
jQuery('#some_other_element').html(response.html);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Took some editing but I finally got it working.